# React-native POST request in android over https return network error

Tags: android, post, https, react-native, axios

Tried to create user account through https POST request under react-native with axios, while it always failed on android with a 'network error'.

```
axios('https://'+DEST_URI, {
 method: 'post',
 data: account,
 headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
 }
 then(...)
```

The same https POST request works fine on iOS.

Changed to http, the same POST request works on android as well.

Also tried GET request through https on android, it could retrieve data from the backend server as expected.

Any idea about it?

Linked image is the output from console log, 
[output from console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg5Us.png)

Comment: Are you using an Android device, and if so, are you using localhost as part of your URI?

Comment: I believe you can easly response to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48223906/949003 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to the issue [Upgrade to OkHttp3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6bbaff2944dafd6fa7e5b77ef46dece0ec2c9983) on the react-native repository.

Deactivate http2 from your proxy that is what causing the problem.
You can try to upgrade to react-native v0.27 they mention in the change log that they fixed this problem but for me didn't work.

I had to disable the http2 feature in ngnix to make it work.

disabling http2 really is this simple, just change this line in your ngnix config file from:

`listen 443 ssl http2;`

to

`listen 443 ssl;`

then reload your config:

`service nginx reload`

More info about http2 and ngnix can be found [here](https://bjornjohansen.no/enable-http2-on-nginx)

Comment: I am with react-native v0.28.  Appreciate your answer as it sounds most relevant to the issue that I encountered. Could you please share how to deactivate http2 in details, and could you share some sample code about it?

Comment: You need to disable it in your proxy/load balance. 
In my case I use ngnix. I'll update my answer and add some reference.

Comment: Thank you Lucas! Just got to know that ngnix is a web server. So the work around is to disable http2 at the back end web server, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. 
This is because the library that react-native uses has a bug with some versions of NGNIX ( at least it was the only webserver/proxy that showed this behaviour )

Comment: Though I use Stamplay as the back end and I am not sure if it uses NGNIX/http2 or not, I would like to mark your answer as the most helpful for this issue, and see if it could be resolved with later version of react-native.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue with android 'POST' requests. Turned out to be headers issue as mentioned in the link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222#issuecomment-170239302

Adding the following headers fixed the issue for me

```
headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken,
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
```

Comment: the link you mentioned is different with mine. There is not a header issue in my case, and the same POST request works over HTTP. It just does not work on android for HTTPS.

Comment: Could you post your code here and a bit more detail about the network error?

Comment: @JohnWei, have you figured out a solution? I'm seeing the exact same issue as you are.. works fine via HTTP but not HTTPS on android

Comment: Hello Ben, the issue disappeared after I upgraded RN to version 0.31

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not a internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Please add this line into you AndroidManifest.xml file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: The INTERNET permission was included in the AndroidManifest.xml file by default for RN app, so this is not the case.