# react-native every next post call has no body

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I have the following issue:

Every next POST call gets the error: Network error

For example, I launch the app and click on the 'subscribe' button which then sends a POST call and gets a response and everything works. But then I click 'unsubscribe' which also sends another POST call, but this time I get a Network error.

Back-end guy tells me that there is no body for request and request was aborted. If I would click button multiple times, then all those requests wouldn't work.

If I would restart the app or wait a few minutes, then 1st post work but posts after that wouldn't

I am using react-native with expo

This is my post method:

```
 export const apiPost = (endpoint, token, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: BASE_URL + endpoint,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': token
      },
      data: data
    }).then(res => resolve(res.data))
      .catch(err => reject(err))
 });
}
```

In case anyone wants to know this is how data passed to POST looks

```
const data = {
  name: "Some value"
}
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "expo": "^30.0.0",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-camera": "^1.2.0",
  "react-native-collapsible": "^1.3.0",
  "react-native-custom-picker": "^0.3.1",
  "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
  "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.2",
  "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.1",
  "react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.2",
  "react-native-search-filter": "^0.1.4",
  "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
  "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
  "react-native-svg": "^6.5.2",
  "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
  "react-native-tab-view": "^1.0.2",
  "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
  "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.1",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "socket.io-client": "2.0.4",
  "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
```

**UPDATE**

I made a test function to make a POST request to https://reqres.in/ and it works fine, even on many requests. So I guess there is an issue in back-end provided to me. Although back-end works fine in Angular app

**UPDATE 2**

The issue was with http2 on back-end. See here : [React-native POST request in android over https return network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171170/react-native-post-request-in-android-over-https-return-network-error)

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the fact that you are returning a Promise which might need then in the actual calling function (although not sure about that).

Try doing it using **async...await** which is much simpler

```
export const apiPost = async (endpoint, token, data) => {
  const data = {
    name: "Some value"
  };
  try {
      const res = await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: BASE_URL + endpoint,
          headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'authorization': token
          },
          data
      });
      return res.json();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err.message;
  }
}
```

Here's the CodeSandBox solution in React (in case I delete it in future) -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useDidMount from "@rooks/use-did-mount";

const fakePost = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "foo",
        body: "bar",
        userId: 1
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err.message;
  }
};

function App() {
  const [fakePostData, setFakePostData] = useState({});
  useDidMount(async () => {
    const res = await fakePost();
    console.log(res);
    setFakePostData(res);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Post fetch example</h1>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(fakePostData)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This also doesn't and I am using .then in calling function.
I believe, that the issue is more in react-native or expo functionality about not adding body to post call or something like that.
I also tried using fetch POST and had same results

Comment: no, the error is not in react-native or expo functionality. it's in your code. wait, i'll try it with some data.

Comment: @Viesturs apparently it works https://codesandbox.io/s/mjqvo58qy9. check console for response :)

Comment: @Viesturs try doing it with `fetch` which is available globally. you don't need to install `axios` or `whatwg-fetch`. also i've tried & tested this many times in react-native & it works. again this is not an issue with react-native or expo like i've said already 

Comment: I tried your solution. And same as before, the first POST call works all good, but second takes about 10 seconds and throws Network request failed
same as here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18432#issuecomment-397851680